# Execute stored procedure and return resultset

Tags: vbscript

I'm a complete VBScript newbie and I am trying to execute a stored procedure and read the resultset. I have tried numerous different approaches using articles online but nothing works and I'm stumped. The database is SQL Server 2008 R2, the application is an off-the-shelf ERP system but I'm able to add my own code to it.

I can execute code by using:

```
connection.execute"insert into blah blah blah"
```

And I can read result set by using:

```
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objRS.Open "select a, b, c FROM blahblah", Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic,    adCmdText
If objRS.EOF = False Then
    a = objRS.Fields("a").Value
    b = objRS.Fields("b").Value
    c = objRS.Fields("c").Value
End If
objRS.Close
```

The stored procedure in question is in effect a select statement e.g.:

```
create procedure [dbname].[dbo].[sptestproc] 
as 
    @Option1 Varchar(10) = NULL,
    @Option2 Varchar(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    select first, second 
    from table1 
    where a = @option1 and b = @toption2
End
```

My code so far:

```
Dim sql

sql = "EXEC [dbname].[dbo].[sptestproc] '" & Opt1 & "','" & Opt2 & "'"
Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open sql, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
Do While Not RS.EOF
    Call App.MessageBox("first",vbInformation,"Data updated")
    Call App.MessageBox("second",vbInformation,"Data updated")
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

But I cannot for the life of me get a procedure to execute and read the results.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the select statement in your stored procedure direct? sql = "select first, second from table1 where a = value and b = value" just to see that it works like that?

Comment: yes it works fine if i do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`adCmdText` would be for SQL query if you want to execute a stored procedure then you have to use `adCmdStoredProc` (value `4` instead)

EDIT:

```
'Set the connection
'...............

'Set the command
DIM cmd
SET cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
SET cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection

'Set the record set
DIM RS
SET RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

'Prepare the stored procedure
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[sptestproc]"
cmd.CommandType = 4  'adCmdStoredProc

cmd.Parameters("@Option1 ") = Opt1 
cmd.Parameters("@Option2 ") = Opt2 

'Execute the stored procedure
SET RS = cmd.Execute
SET cmd = Nothing

'You can now access the record set
if (not RS.EOF) THEN
    first = RS("first")
    second = RS("second")
end if

'dispose your objects
RS.Close
SET RS = Nothing

Connection.Close
SET Connection = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that and it still doesn't work. Anything else you can see that's wrong?

Comment: @RobLaw84 yes another thing is you never executed the command! http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_execute.asp

Comment: Ok thanks, 

Do i execute the command before i create the recordset?:

    sql = "EXEC [M1_KT].[dbo].[spPartConfigGetParts] '" & Opt1 & "','" & Opt2 & "','" & Opt3 & "','" & Opt4 & "'"
    connection.Execute sql
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    RS.Open sql, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic,  adCmdStoredProc

I though opening the recordsset would execute it automatically, like when i did a simple select statement.

I've tried it before and after but it doesn't work, sorry for my ignorance but i've never done any vbscript work before, this is completely new to me

Answer (score 0):

Connection.Execute "SET NOCOUNT ON"

Before

SET cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection

I went well.

Comment: The original question does not contain a line like `SET cmd.ActiveConnection` so it is unclear what is the proposed change here. Maybe this answer was intended as a comment on the  other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706415/511016 instead?

Comment: If you don't use command object,you may insert Connection.Execute "SET NOCOUNT ON"  berfore objRS.Open method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sql

Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@option1", adVarChar, adParamInput, , Opt1)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@option2", adVarChar, adParamInput, , Opt2)
cmd.Parameters.Append prm

cmd.CommandText = "[dbname].[dbo].[sptestproc]"
Set Com.ActiveConnection = Connection
'Connection must be opend already
RS.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

Do While Not RS.EOF
    Call App.MessageBox("first",vbInformation,"Data updated")
    Call App.MessageBox("second",vbInformation,"Data updated")
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
```