# Stored Procedure works when called directly but not as an execute from Website

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server Express 2014 (shown as an "alter procedure" statement). If I run it directly "execute stored procedure", it runs fine and inserts data into `weatherdata`. If I run it remotely, the insert doesn't work. I don't get any error messages. Everything else works fine, I have a similar stored procedure that uploads from file.xml into wsdatatemp. They will be a single stored procedure but have split them to isolate the problem.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[fivedayforecast2]   
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

    SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM energymaplocs.dbo.wsdatatemp

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML;

    INSERT INTO energymaplocs.dbo.weatherdata ([ws_id], [windspeed], [winddirection],[ws_mins], [ws_date])
        SELECT *
        FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'SiteRep/DV/Location/Period/Rep',2)
        WITH 
            (ws_id int '../../@i',
             windspeed int '@S',
             winddirection [varchar](3) '@D',
             ws_mins int '@myrep',
             ws_date datetime '../@value'
            )

    --EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
END
```

So, above when run from SQL Server Management Studio runs fine but when called as below, seems to run without any errors but doesn't populate weatherdata using the insert

```
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

conn.Open strConnection

sql2 = "exec energymaplocs.dbo.fivedayforecast2"    
set rs = conn.execute(sql2)

rs.close
conn.close
```

Comment: possible duplicate - execute as a stored procedure correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706258/execute-stored-procedure-and-return-resultset

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/300488/how-to-run-sql-server-stored-procedures-from-an-asp-page) might help

Comment: btw: `FROM OPENXML` (together with the SPs to prepare and to remove a document) is outdated and should not be used anymore. I'd suggest to start a second question with a (reduced!) example of your XML to find out, how you can read this with XML's native methods.