# Stored procedure does not return record set

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, wincc

I have been working on debugging a script. Working through other issues from the first post. I come to a stop at this point where I receive an error @ `rst.Open cmd.Execute`. This only happens when running stored procedure `dbo.BoreRecipe` and not `dbo.SawRecipe`:

```vb
'strSql = "dbo.BoreRecipe"
strSql = "dbo.BoreRecipeTest"
'strSql = "dbo.SawRecipe" 

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

cmd.NamedParameters = True

'Need to set to parameters in stored procedure
'Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter(@WO, adVarChar, adParamInput, 8)
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@WO")
cmd.Parameters("@WO").Value = sWO

'Get Recordset and Process
rst.Open cmd.Execute
```

[image: Error Code 800A0BB9]

Both stored procedure seem to be of the same formatting. We did add a script to SQL to add a missing value to an existing field of the `dbo.BoreRecipie` but did not add any other fields. That's about the time this started. It appears the with the `On Error Resume Next` statement would cause the script to return garbage since there was no information in the record due to the error.

Comment: If you weren't connected it would have errored. Does it error?

Comment: I have tried to get it to error by putting in the wrong information in the connection string. and still get the same results. No error that's in part where some of the confusion lies.

Comment: OK found an issue the script contains 'on error resume next' I removed it now I get alot of errors. Will need to revisit this question once I work through some of the new bugs.

Comment: I get error an error @ rst.Open. Which most likely has nothing to do with my initial question. On error resume next was keeping me from seeing any errors. This script was copied an pasted from another system which we are having issues with. I have a feeling it would throw the same error but they have that line of code.

Error '800a0e7d' 
The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute stored procedure and return resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706258/execute-stored-procedure-and-return-resultset)

Comment: So I have spent most of my day working this issue. The issue happens when I call one stored procedure over another. One stops at  `rst.Open cmd.Execute`  the other returns appropriate values.

Comment: I feel a need to close this as my problem is way different then what I started with